# “Osteopatia” in italiano versus “osteopathy” in inglese

Tags: word-meaning, english-comparison, single-words

Buongiorno,

Questo post concerne se l'uso della parola osteopatia in inglese ha dei significati diversi dall'uso di questa parola in italiano. I dizionari Merriam-Webster e Treccani esibiscono le seguenti definizioni. Mi stupisce che il dizionario inglese parla di "structural integrity" che mi fa pensare che qui non si tratta di solo ossa, e "terapeutical measures" mi fa pensare ad un tiraossa invece che ad un osteopata. Invece in italiano un osteopata dovrebbe operare sulle ossa e nervi e vasi sanguigni attaccati alle ossa tramite interventi chirurgici se ho capito bene.

Grazie per la chiarificazione.

---

Definition of osteopathy

: a system of medical practice based on a theory that diseases are due chiefly to loss of structural integrity which can be restored by manipulation of the parts supplemented by therapeutic measures (such as use of drugs or surgery)

osteòpata s. m. e f. [tratto da osteopatia] (pl. m. -i). – Chi pratica l'osteopatia.

osteopatia Qualsiasi processo morboso, localizzato o sistemico, dell’apparato scheletrico.

Disciplina sanitaria rivolta al trattamento, mediante manipolazioni, di sintomatologie dolorose e menomazioni funzionali dell’apparato osteo-artro-muscolare.

Comment: Non so bene che cosa sia wordreference, ma le definizioni italiane vengono dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/osteopatia).
Quanto alla parola in sé, è una coniazione infelice in qualsiasi lingua (per non parlare della disciplina nel suo complesso): vedi per esempio il cap. 16 di _Fads and Fallacies_ di Martin Gardner.

Comment: Comunque, fad o meno, sia in italiano che in inglese si parla soprattutto di manipulations/manipolazioni.

Comment: Non sono un'esperta nella materia, ma credo che la questione è che lo stesso vocabolo è stato usato per un certo tipo di fisioterapia e una pseudo-scienza. La definizione del Treccani sembra fare riferimento a questo certo tipo di fisioterapia (non vedo che alluda a nessun intervento chirurgico però), mentre la definizione del Merriam-Webster sembra essere quella della pseudo-scienza.

Comment: La domanda sarebbe: quando qualcuno parla di "osteopatia" in italiano sta pensando a un certo tipo di fisioterapia, mentre invece la parola "osteopathy" in inglese è di solito usata per riferirsi a una pseudo-scienza?

Comment: Ah, e come dice @DaG, si tratta di una coniazione infelice perché la stessa parola può anche essere usata per riferirsi a una malattia ossea.

Comment: @Charo: Non me ne intendo specificamente, ma mi sembra che anche in italiano designi solo una pseudoscienza (altrimenti si chiama fisioterapia o altro). Se googli rapidamente, trovi solo sedicenti “Istituto superiore di osteopatia”, “Centro studi di osteopatia tradizionale” etc. che sembrano tutti rifarsi alle baggianat... teorie di Andrew Taylor Still. Credo che il Treccani abbia semplicemente deciso di non sbilanciarsi.

Answer (score 1):

Io considererei l’etimologia della parola: osteopatia, e quindi ostheopathy, come molti termini medici deriva dal greco antico: **ὀστέον** (ostéon)  = osso + **πάθος** (páthos) = sofferenza.

Il senso letterale è **"patologia ossea"**, ma in entrambe le lingue il termine viene utilizzato per definire la terapia.

Come cita [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/patia/), il suffisso **-patia** in medicina, indica affezioni diverse, facendo generico riferimento, o all’organo o sistema interessato, o al meccanismo patogenetico, o alle condizioni di insorgenza. **In qualche caso, designa particolari metodi di cura.**

> **Italiano:** è una terapia alternativa che consiste nella manipolazione di alcune parti del corpo, in particolare la schiena, il collo e la testa.
>
> **English:** Osteopathy is a type of alternative medicine that emphasizes manual readjustments.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteopathy#Worldwide), alla voce Osteopathy, fornisce una lista di paesi e del loro approccio legale alla pratica medica osteopatica, ulteriore dimostrazione del fatto che il termine viene utilizzato più per definire la terapia che la patologia.